# Mirrored drive separated and lost one copy

Tags: raid, partition, mirroring

I have a dedicated server with two identical hard drives, which ran in a raid array, mirrored until yesterday, when the datacenter had a power failure and corrupted one of the discs. I figured if I 'break' the mirror (not 'remove'), I would be able to get TWO identical copies of the data, one on the bad drive and one on the good drive. But alas, after performing the 'break mirror' command, the resulting partition on the 'good' drive appears to be blank and asks me to format it. Bummer!

Now, the support guy tells me I should backup the bad partition onto the free one, but before doing so, I am asking, is there any chance of recovering the data on the seemingly blank partition now? I did not get any prompts from Windows asking me if I was 'sure' that the data would be lost, only the warning that the disks will not be 'redundant' anymore.

I would appreciate any insight.

Thanks

Comment: You were implementing the RAID how? Particular network card? Software based? Windows built-in RAID?

Comment: I'm guessing Software based. based on the last sentancein the second paragraph.

Comment: Why would they be asking you to "mirror" data from a known bad drive to the good drive, with corruption along with it?

Comment: You could try putting the disk in a computer and booting a Linux bootable disc with it and run Testdisk to see what you can find, but be aware that attempts to retrieve data can end up corrupting the drive more.

Comment: Also, there's a possibility (someone here knows more about it no doubt) that the drive is just tagged with a special flag as "RAID", so the standard drive access is seeing it as blank or corrupt when in reality it's just expecting it to be part of a mirror RAID. Does the "bad" drive show up with data and can it be read without problems?

Comment: Last...I take it that wiping and re-creating the RAID volume and restoring from backup isn't an option?

Comment: I currently can see and access all partitions on the BAD drive. The mirrored array had two partitions -- I have only specified 'break mirror' on the larger partition, where I store the data. The resulting partition on the GOOD drive appears as 100% empty and the system cannot see it. I guess I could format it but I want to save data, particularly one database backup which I could not recover from the raid array -- I was hoping that the good drive will have a non-corrupted copy of that and I might extract it but seems like there's no joy.

Comment: From what I've read around, the 'break mirror' command should not touch the data in any way, just give me TWO sets of partitions with identical data, no? I am bummed as to why this didn't happen. I know I was not drunk to say 'remove mirror'!

Comment: @Cristi: If you have a spare system...or want to risk it on your current computer...you can try the Rescue Is Possible (RIP) Linux disc and see if running Testdisk will retrieve data. But again, any attempt to alter or save data on a drive with a tool you're unfamiliar with can damage data even more. I'd suggest removing the drive you have some data still accessible in so you don't accidentally access that, and get an external drive to write data to. If you're unfamiliar with Linux, using that disc will be very difficult...

Comment: @Bart, they are not asking me to mirror data from the bad drive, just asking me to 'save' whatever I want onto the newly created blank partition, but I want to still try to see whether I could restore anything from that partition before I completely wipe it.

Comment: @Bart, I am afraid I can't do much fiddling around with Linux and such since this is a server in a datacenter in a different country. I am relying on the Remote Desktop client for anything I do.

Comment: @Cristi: by mirror I meant copy. If there's corruption on the drive, you're going to copy corrupted data. As for recovering data remotely? Ouch. That was probably a detail to put in the question if you can edit it. That kind of limits what you can or can't do.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that by specifying 'dedicated server' would kind of be obvious that I don't have physical access to the server but then again, I am sure it's possible that server admins would be using this site :) I am sure the guy at the datacenter is very willing to help but I don't think he'd go as far as trying to do data recovery for me -- he's just anxious to replace the hard drive and move on to the next 200 broken machines by the power failure.

Answer (score 1):

Mirroring:data safety == TSA uniform:flight safety. 
Windows mirror setups are often all but useless in practice, since whatever corrupts one drive can easily corrupt the other. You're better off to use the second drive as permanent backup media and keep backups as often as practical.

Depending on your actual Windows OS [and the precise details of your dedicated host, which may not be dedicated after all], you may be able to inspect the drive using some other tools. If the data was ever actually on the drive, some form of sector recovery tool might allow you to get the data back. If it shows as blank, it may be just that the filesystem structure is missing from the drive. Have you used fdisk to have a look? There are several windows based recovery tools that might be able to recreate the drive structure.

Comment: Yes, try connecting the drive to a computer and try accessing it using one of the free file recovery tools.  I was actually just in the middle of installing PC Inspector File Recovery to recover data from a flash drive. It's a Windows based free/basic file recovery tool.

Comment: Hmm... I've had very good luck with Windows software RAID all the way back to NT 4.0. It's true that I've had it faithfully "replicate" filesystem corruption onto both members of a RAID-1 set, but I'd had hardware RAID controllers do that do. For an "on the cheap" solution to make a server fault "resilient" against single disk failure, though, Windows RAID 1 works pretty well and the price is right for me.